# Use jQuery script on data that has been loaded with .load()

Tags: jquery, html, load

I have a webpage that I have been playing around with jQuery on.

It has a couple of animations, some .post stuff and there is also a div that .load()s a page every 5 seconds.

In this .load() data, which lists a bunch of database entries, I have delete buttons next to each entry.

I want to use those buttons, with jQuery, to delete the item with a post call, but the problem is, jQuery from my script doesn't work on the html that was called via .load().

I have seen some people saying "use .on" but I'm not able to find out how to use it to accomplish my goal, some insight from you guys / girls would be much appreciated.

Here is an example of what I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="load_data">

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).load(function(){

    $("#load_data").load('test.html');

    $("#change_loaded").click(function(){

        $("#loaded").empty().append('Now the data is updated.');
    })

})
```

test.html

```
<button id="change_loaded">Click</button>

<div id="loaded">

This is what I want to change with the jQuery but it isn't working

</div>
```

With this example, when I click on the change_loaded button, it doesn't do anything because the jQuery hasn't been loaded for that page yet. What I'd like to know is what is the correct way of loading the jQuery code for the html that has been put inside the div with .load().

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a delegated event handler for the dynamic content

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#load_data").load('test.html');
    $("#load_data").on('click', '#change_loaded', function(){
           $("#loaded").empty().append('Now the data is updated.');
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect, I understand now how .on works, and how to delegate a function to data loaded externally.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because event listeners are bound when the DOM loads.  When you insert dynamic content, no event listeners are attached.  By using `.on`, you delegate the listener to a static DOM element that is a parent of the dynamic content so any event on the child will bubble up to the parent that has the event attached to it.